# Web Api con .Net Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Trabajo con Visual Studio Community 2019
Trabajo en un proyecto de web api con .Net Framework implemente un controlador el cual si me funciona pero al implementar Automapper y sobrecargar e constructor me da error.

Controller

```
    namespace Prueba.WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class CategoryController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly CategoryRepository _categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository();

        public CategoryController(IMapper mapper)
        {
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<CategoryDto> Index()
        {
            var result = _categoryRepository.GetAll();
            var listCategoryDto = _mapper.Map<List<CategoryDto>>(result);
            return listCategoryDto;
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping

```
namespace Prueba.WebApi
{
    public class AutomapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutomapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CategoryExtend, CategoryDto>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
}
```

Global.asax

```
namespace Prueba.WebApi
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
    {
  "Message": "Error.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Error al intentar crear un controlador de tipo 'CategoryController'. Asegúrese de que el controlador tenga un constructor público sin parámetros.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
  "StackTrace": "   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
  "InnerException": {
    "Message": "Error.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "El tipo 'Prueba.WebApi.Controllers.CategoryController' no tiene un constructor predeterminado",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
    "StackTrace": "   en System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New(Type type)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Internal.TypeActivator.Create[TBase](Type instanceType)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.GetInstanceOrActivator(HttpRequestMessage request, Type controllerType, Func`1& activator)\r\n   en System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)"
  }
}
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Ya incluyó, en la factoría, un constructor para instancias de IMapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo lo hago de la siguiente manera :

Clase: MapeoGenerico

```
public class MapeoGenerico : Profile
    {
        public MapeoGenerico(){
            CreateMap<Category, CategoryDto>().IncludeAllDerived();
            CreateMap<CategoryDto, Category>().IncludeAllDerived();
        }
    }
```

Controller :

```
public class CategoryController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;
        private readonly CategoryRepository _categoryRepository = new CategoryRepository();

        public CategoryController()
        {
           var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddProfile<MapeoGenerico>());
        _mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<CategoryDto> Index()
        {
            var result = _categoryRepository.GetAll();
            var listCategoryDto = _mapper.Map<List<CategoryDto>>(result);
            return listCategoryDto;
        }
    }
```

Si no tienes la clase `MapeoGenerico` creala y dentro ingresa todos entities y models que deseas mapear.

Espero te ayude saludos.

Comment: Hi, si tengo mapeado lo que tengo una duda es como configurar el start de automapper lo tengo configurado en Global..asax, muestro el profile

Comment: Hola en tu caso seria de esta forma `var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.cfg.AddProfile<AutomapperProfile>());`

Comment: En tu ejemplo declaras _mapper en el constructor mapper pero nunca lo igualas, si he probado como comentas y me da el mismo error creo me esta faltando hacer uso de un framework de IoC

Comment: Hola modificare lo que he hecho porque me adherí a lo que tenias hecho por favor revisa bien el categorycontroller que ahí hare el cambio, perdón la confusión.

Comment: Marque la respuesta porque si funciono con la corrección que hiciste, pero para ponerlo de manera global en Global.asax lo intente de esta manera `var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.AddMaps(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()));` halgo falta

Comment: Hola creo que esto te puede ayudar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284723/how-to-registr-automapper-configuration-class-in-global-asax